# How to recover missing notes since Mavericks update?

Tags: macos, notes.app

Very recently I've updated my computer via the Mac App Store to Mavericks. Today when I opened Notes I noticed the background had changed but even more startling was that all my notes were **gone**! It shows "error 43".

I have an external hard drive and backed up my computer.

Is there any way to get my notes back?

Comment: You should expand your question, to include the text of the error message.  Where did the error come up? Also what do you mean updated?  Did you purchase Mac OS X 10.9 and update? Or did you just update an app?  Other than that, if you were using, TimeMachine for backups you should be able to recover your notes.

Answer (score 3):

The notes should be stored in your backup, at least. Check here

Solution is to navigate to ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes and restore:

NotesV1.storedata
NotesV1.storedata-shm
NotesV1.storedata-wal

Where ~ is your home directory e.g. /Users/your_username

Refer [macrumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1453392)
or [apple discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19171700#19171700#19171700)
for more info.

Answer (score 2):

This should fix the problem:
**Note: If you do not have an Apple ID, that means your Notes are completely lost.**

1. Go to Finder.
2. Click on Applications.
3. Find System Preferences.
4. Click on iCloud.
5. Log in to your iCloud account if you have not logged in yet.
6. Select the Notes checkbox.

Comment: This did not locate my notes. Could it be that only notes that were saved on the cloud are recoverable? Very disappointing any other ideas?

Comment: Notes was already checked for me, but unchecking and then rechecking them did the trick.